# Reference table: MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working a [project euler problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=22) and it calls for me to sort a text file of names, then assign a value to each letter in the name based on its alphabetic position (ie, 'Bob' = 2, 15, 2).

I was thinking of approaching the problem using something like the VLOOKUP function in excel. I wanted to create a reference column vector with the letters in the alphabet in alphabetic order - each letter's position in the reference vector is its "value". Then I can take an entry in my name table, say "BOB", and lookup the values B, O, and B in the reference vector, outputting their position and therefore the value of each letter.

My question: how do you reference values in one matrix to values in another vector? Thanks for your help with this everybody.

Comment: @iCodez: Oh! I was wondering why all these project-euler questions kept popping up!

Comment: @knedlsepp - Yea, sorry about bombing the 'active' page. :)  We're currently burninating the tag.  It should be destroyed within the hour.

Answer (score 1):

Unless performance is a real concern here, I wouldn't bother with a lookup table.  There's a simple way to convert your characters into numbers.

Take each of your strings, upper case them using `upper`, subtract off 'A' and add one to convert all 'A's into '1's, 'B's into '2's, etc.

```
s = 'Bob';
num_s = upper(s) - 'A' + 1;
```

---

> I am still curious maybe for my own development to learn how to examine a character, match it to an entry in another vector and recall a value it corresponds to. – user1499689

To do this is easy in Matlab.  Let's say you have a lookup table of 26 elements, `lookup`

```
lookup = zeros(26,1);
% define the lookup table
for i=1:numel(lookup)
  lookup(i) = 2*i - 7;   % some random function
end
```

Now, using the char-to-number conversion above:

```
s =

Joe

>> lookup( upper(s) - 'A' + 1 )

ans =

    13
    23
     3
```

The key here is that Matlab allows you to index any matrix with another matrix: `M(A)`.  The elements of the matrix `A` are treated as indices into the matrix `M`.  Your string `s` is a char matrix, which you convert into a numeric matrix by subtracting `'A'`.  The line `lookup(...)` then uses the elements of this converted matrix to index the matrix `lookup`.

This, incidentally, can be used for assignment as well.  For example, if you wanted to keep a count of each character (independent of case):

```
% Initialize counts to zero somewhere at the beginning
counts = zeros(26,1);

... % do your stuff

% let 's' be an alphabetic word (only A-Z and a-z)
s_inds = upper(s) - 'A' + 1;
counts( s_inds ) = counts( s_inds ) + 1;  % increment the counts of all characters in 's'
```

Comment: This is awesome help - definitely a better solution. Thanks everyone. I am still curious maybe for my own development to learn how to examine a character, match it to an entry in another vector and recall a value it corresponds to.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a means of generating a look-up table of sorts.  We'll go with the general example you have here.  There's 26 letters in the alphabet, case in-sensitive.

```
Basic_lookup = 1:26; % Note: this can be changed up if you want some level of randomness.
% Basic_lookup = randperm(26); % I like this a bit better for randomness sake.  And is just an example of making it random.
```

Now this is a single row vector going from 1 to 26.  All you need to do is simply go through the string that you have value by value and call the value you need from the lookup table.  @sfstewman details this to some extent in their post.  You can easily adapt from that.

Comment: Also, just a note... If you want to take case into account you'll need to adapt the above code to accomidate for upper and lower cases.